# Is there any free open source chart library available for iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone

Is there any free open source chart library available for iphone/ipad ?

Comment: http://www.keepedge.com/

Comment: Need to check this: http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/useful-open-source-libraries-for-iphone-development/

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: http://www.ivisualization.com/

Comment: also look for alternate option through java script: 

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=449621

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/linegraph.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is such a library.

Answer (score 0):

Tapku library has a line plot chart

http://tapku.com

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Graph