# What is the best Graph and Chart Library available for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, graph

What is  the best Graph and Chart Library available for iPhone and iPad?

The Library also should be interactive like allowing individual elements in graph to be touched and events trapped for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph generation on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794562/graph-generation-on-iphone)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Core-plot](https://github.com/core-plot) is an open source library that's been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493094/is-there-any-free-open-source-chart-library-available-for-iphone-ipad) before.

Comment: Can you suggest a Library which could be paid and provides better facilities than Core-Plot?

Comment: Core-plot is quite a comprehensive framework. I've yet to come across anything more advanced.

Comment: Does that support interactiveness? Like when I touch on the graph, a small view should display its corresponding value?

Comment: Not sure about your exact example, but core-plot certainly supports similar sorts of interactivity.

Comment: Core plot is good for small datasets, but it's really slow. There's a performance comparison here which compares against iOS-Charts, Coreplot, and two commercial charts for larger datasets, or frequent update: 

https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison/

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at [PowerPlot](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de) which is an iOS native library and is available under a dual license policy - you can choose either the GPLv3 or a commercial (proprietary) license.

I have written an app (in-house for a client) with it that uses interactive graphs.

As for "the best" library: That depends on what you are looking for. PowerPlot is the only option (to my knowledge) that allows you to also draw graphs (nodes & connections) along with other chart types. So if you look for that versatility, PowerPlot is the "best." If you look for simplicity, it may not be.

Answer (score 2):

[SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) is the best chart & graph library for iOS, iPhone and iPad.

It can:

- Draw line charts, bar charts, scatter charts, mountain charts, column charts
- Draw candlestick charts, OHLC charts
- Draw heatmaps / spectrograms
- Support multiple X,Y axis, tooltips, legends
- Support zooming, panning and scaling via touch
- Do all this at blazing speed

It is also [rated 5* by its users](http://www.scichart.com/read-testimonials).

[image]

Have a look at the [introductory video](https://youtu.be/rfJsWVm4Epc) for more info.

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the scichart project*